# ClassCastException while reading from Infinispan Cache after redeployment on Wildfly 8.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, classcastexception, infinispan

I have a simple Infinispan local-cache (also tried distributed cache) on Wildfly 8.2. Everything is working fine until I do redeployment of my .WAR. After redeployment of my .WAR I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: my.package.MyClass cannot be cast to my.package.MyClass
```

Full stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/bagges/07af1842a874f7c99ef3

I lookup the Cache in a CDI Bean like this:

```
@Path("/mypath")
@Stateless
public class MyServiceClass {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/myContainer")
    private CacheContainer container;

    private Cache<Integer, MyCacheObject> myCache;

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        myCache = container.getCache("myCache");
    }

    @GET
    public String get() {
        if(!myCache.containsKey(1)) {
            myCache.put(1, new MyCacheObject(1, "Hello Cache"));
        }
        return myCache.get(1).getName();
    }
}
```

Wildfly-Config:

```
<cache-container name="myContainer" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/myContainer" start="EAGER">
    <local-cache name="myCache"/>
</cache-container>
```

I know that the error occured because off different class loaders. Infinispan tries to cast the entity stored with the previous classloader which cannot work. But how to avoid this?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace on gist or pastebin? What does your Wildfly configuration look like?

Comment: added stacktrace and configuration. Any idea @GalderZamarreño?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use start="EAGER".  That will fix your problem.
We've removed this from WildFly 9, since its misuse has been the source of many user headaches.

Also, I recommend injecting your cache directly (instead of just the cache container).  That way the cache lifecycle will be bound to the lifecycle of your deployment.
e.g.

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/myContainer/myCache")
private Cache<Integer, MyCacheObject> myCache;
```

Lastly, feel free to use a resource-ref to avoid referencing a vendor-specific jndi namespace in your application.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. If I use start="LAZY", the redeployment problem is gone. But only because the cache is evicted during redeployment. The previously stored objects are gone. I can still not access the cache from another EAR/WAR. It will still throw the ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to share the cache if you enable `store-as-binary` in the Infinispan configuration and you force the cache to use the application's classloader instead of the one in the `GlobalConfiguration`:

```
Cache appSpecificCache = cacheFromJndi.getAdvancedCache().with(applicationClassLoader)
```